# How do I interlace two Rust vectors into a new vector?

Tags: vector, rust, iterator, traits, rust-itertools

I need an idiomatic way to interlace these two vectors:

```
v1 = vec![1.0, 2.0, 3.0];
v2 = vec![4.0, 5.0, 6.0];
```

The output I expect is:

```
v3 is [1.0, 4.0, 2.0, 5.0, 3.0, 6.0];
```

I attempted using itertool's `interlace` function, but I can't get the iterators to collect to `Vec` types. It's likely I'm using them wrong.

Comment: With std iter : https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=50c0cc820c1ac3b244a3138d2f141407

Comment: @ÖmerErden And soon, when `IntoIter` is implemented for arrays, you won't need the weird `once` chaining :)

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios I wish tuples had `IntoIter` implementation, until then let's just stick to this `.flat_map(|(x, y)| vec![x,y])` :P

Comment: Well done, thanks Omer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`interleave()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.2/itertools/fn.interleave.html) function or [`interleave()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.2/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.interleave) method from [Itertools](https://crates.io/crates/itertools) crate:

```rust
use itertools::{interleave, Itertools};

fn main() {
    let v1 = vec![1.0, 2.0, 3.0];
    let v2 = vec![4.0, 5.0, 6.0];
    let v = interleave(v1, v2).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    dbg!(v);

    let v1 = vec![1.0, 2.0, 3.0];
    let v2 = vec![4.0, 5.0, 6.0];
    let v = v1
        .into_iter()
        .interleave(v2.into_iter())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    dbg!(v);
}
```